# Why can't selenium locate the 'Send Me a Push' button?

Tags: python, selenium

The page I'm trying to access requires 2FA. If I click the 'Send Me a Push' button, it will send a request to my phone to approve. However, when I try to find the button via the following methods, I get a NoSuchElementException (or timeout if I ask selenium to wait for the element to be clickable). Methods used:

```
driver.find_element()
- By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[2]/p[2]/input'
- By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#auth_methods button'
- By.CLASS_NAME, 'positive.auth-button'
```

Comment: There is no **Send Me a Push** button within the [HTML](https://pastebin.com/KdWNmZJF) Update the question with the text based relevant html.

Comment: Have you actually **looked** at the html you posted?  None of those things are present on the page...

Comment: But that page does have an `<iframe>`, which is a common cause of errors like this.  If the desired element is inside the iframe, you have to tell specifically selenium to switch to the frame with `driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_element)`

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you so much for identifying the problem. You were right. Switching to the iframe fixed it! How do I select your answer as the right one? Also, for the future, how do I get all the code in Chrome web dev mode to post to pastebin? I've tried right clicking the html tag and selecting 'Edit as HTML' but that only gives me the same html as the 'View Page Source' option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page has an `<iframe>`, which is a common cause of errors like this.  Elements in the iframe are *not* actually part of the page source.

If the desired element is inside the iframe, you have to specifically tell selenium to switch to the frame with `driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_element)`